# Can a row be updated more than once in the same UPDATE FROM query?

Tags: sqlite

Perhaps a better title would be: How to ensure that a row is not updated more than once in the same UPDATE FROM query.

(These two simple examples were run in the SQLite Fiddle.)

I'm resetting a column of integer key values to a new order using `UPDATE...FROM...` and am uncertain about what takes place when a value is changed to that of another row. If there were a unique constraint on `start_key`, there would be a conflict; but there are no constraints on this table.

For instance, in the first update query, after the first row's `start_key` is set to `3`, can the subsequent updates ever match it against an `orig.start_key` of `3`? In other words, when the third row is reached that has an original `start_key` of `3`, can the `WHERE` clause return two rows (since the first has already been updated to 3) and update row 1 again? Such that row 1 would be updated a second time to `5 5 'a'`. That did not occur in this simple example but will it always be the case that a row can be updated only once?

And, if one wants to avoid any such possibility of that, can the `rowid` be relied upon at least over the life of an extended CTE query, such as done in the second `UPDATE...FROM ...` query?

Thank you for considering my question.

```
drop table if exists test;
create table test (start_key integer, end_key integer, value text);
insert into test values
 (1,15,'a'), 
 (2,11,'b'), 
 (3,25,'c'), 
 (4,31,'d') 
;
select * from test;
/*
start_key  end_key  value
---------  -------  -----
1          15       a    
2          11       b    
3          25       c    
4          31       d    
*/
.param set :max_key 2
with
orig as
(
 select 
    start_key,
    :max_key + row_number() over (order by start_key) as new_key
 from
    test
)
update test as u
  set 
    start_key = g.new_key,
    end_key = g.new_key
from 
  orig g
where
   g.start_key = u.start_key
;
select * from test;
/*
start_key  end_key  value
---------  -------  -----
3          3        a    
4          4        b    
5          5        c    
6          6        d 
*/
drop table if exists test;
create table test (start_key integer, end_key integer, value text);
insert into test values
 (1,15,'a'), 
 (2,11,'b'), 
 (3,25,'c'), 
 (4,31,'d') 
;
with
orig as
(
 select
    rowid as o_rowid,
    :max_key + row_number() over (order by start_key) as new_key
 from
    test
)
update test as u
set
   start_key = g.new_key,
   end_key = g.new_key
from
   orig g
where
   u.rowid = g.o_rowid
;
select * from test;
/*
start_key  end_key  value
---------  -------  -----
3          3        a    
4          4        b    
5          5        c    
6          6        d 
*/
```